# PHP converting yy to yyyy using strtotime and date while forcing dates in past

Tags: php, strtotime

I am parsing a dates ranging from 1950s to ~2021 stored in mm/dd/yy format. Using `date('Y-m-d',strtotime($time));` works for all dates past 1970, but it is struggling with dates prior to that. Dates like `02/26/63` become `2063-02-26` instead of `1963-02-26`.

Is there a way to force cutoff year after which all dates will be considered 2000s instead of 1900s? Or should I abandon `strtotime()` in general and parse the string myself?

Using the following php version

`PHP 7.1.8 (cli) (built: Dec 18 2017 22:20:57) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you really have no way to force PHP to do something differently you are better off parsing out at least the year and adding the 19 to it. You may then use the [DateTime](http://php.net/DateTime) functions to manipulate it further.

```
$thedate = '02/26/63';
$year = substr($thedate,-2);
$year = ($year < 70 ? '19' : '20') . $year;
echo $year;
```